# Neo4j Bus Route Application Modeling

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases

My question is I have one graph with lot of nodes representing stops of buses.
How should I include bus information like which buses available between nodes.

I am thinking of creating a buses relationship between nodes that will have info of all the buses between two nodes and a relationship property marking distance between two stops.

```
      buses[500A,182A],distance:500m     buses[121B,542W,222A,111Z],distance:400m
```

Like   A------------------------------------------------------->B----------------------------------------------------------->C

So how I will find out the bus or busses( If no direct path is available) to reach M from A?

First I will find out the path (a neo4j query) , how to reach M from A .

Say my path is

```
buses[11A],distance:1000m    buses[11A],distance:250m   buses[13B,100A],distance:2000m
```

A----------------------------------------->L----------------------------------->N------------------------------------------->M

The problem is I how to programmatically check whether a direct bus to M is available or not , or I how to interchange the bus in between.

According to above scenario I can go A to N through 11A then from N to M by taking either 13B or 100A.

I have to do that programmatically.

I want to retrieve all possible paths between two stations and total distance of a path along with bus information.

Comment: Do you want to minimize distance or the number of transfers?

Comment: I want to get all possible routes with bus interchange info alonng with total dstancce of each path.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your model needs to be more graphy-y. That is, I don't think you should have an array property on the relationship between Stop nodes with the bus information. Rather, the buses should be nodes themselves with a relationship to indicate which stops they stop at. Consider the following example data:

```
CREATE (a:Stop {name:'A'}),
       (b:Stop {name:'B'}),
       (c:Stop {name:'C'}),
       (d:Stop {name:'D'}),

       (a)-[:NEXT {distance:1}]->(b),
       (b)-[:NEXT {distance:2}]->(c),
       (c)-[:NEXT {distance:3}]->(d),

       (b1:Bus {id:1}),
       (b2:Bus {id:2}),
       (b3:Bus {id:3}),

       (b1)-[:STOPS_AT]->(a),
       (b1)-[:STOPS_AT]->(b),
       (b2)-[:STOPS_AT]->(a),
       (b2)-[:STOPS_AT]->(b),
       (b2)-[:STOPS_AT]->(c),
       (b3)-[:STOPS_AT]->(b),
       (b3)-[:STOPS_AT]->(c),
       (b3)-[:STOPS_AT]->(d);
```

The graph now looks like this:

[image: model]

With this model, it's easy to find an itinerary that minimizes the number of transfers and also returns all the necessary transfer information, if applicable. For example, all shortest itineraries (shortest in terms of # of transfers) from A to D:

```
MATCH (a:Stop {name:'A'}), (d:Stop {name:'D'})
MATCH p = allShortestPaths((a)-[:STOPS_AT*]-(d))
RETURN EXTRACT(x IN NODES(p) | CASE WHEN x:Stop THEN 'Stop ' + x.name
                                    WHEN x:Bus THEN 'Bus ' + x.id
                               ELSE '' END) AS itinerary
```

Three routes were found, which all have one transfer:

```
Stop A, Bus 2, Stop C, Bus 3, Stop D
Stop A, Bus 1, Stop B, Bus 3, Stop D
Stop A, Bus 2, Stop B, Bus 3, Stop D
```

Of course, you can return this information however you want with the `EXTRACT()` function.

Another example. Find an itinerary from A to C:

```
MATCH (a:Stop {name:'A'}), (c:Stop {name:'C'})
MATCH p = allShortestPaths((a)-[:STOPS_AT*]-(c))
RETURN EXTRACT(x IN NODES(p) | CASE WHEN x:Stop THEN 'Stop ' + x.name
                                    WHEN x:Bus THEN 'Bus ' + x.id
                               ELSE '' END)
```

One route was found, and there are no transfers:

```
Stop A, Bus 2, Stop C
```

Please let me know if this answers your question.

EDIT: To get the distance:

```
MATCH (a:Stop {name:'A'}), (d:Stop {name:'D'})
MATCH route = allShortestPaths((a)-[:STOPS_AT*]-(d)),
      stops = (a)-[:NEXT*]->(d)
RETURN EXTRACT(x IN NODES(route) | CASE WHEN x:Stop THEN 'Stop ' + x.name
                                        WHEN x:Bus THEN 'Bus ' + x.id
                                   ELSE '' END) AS itinerary,
       REDUCE(d = 0, x IN RELATIONSHIPS(stops) | d + x.distance) AS distance


                           itinerary  distance
Stop A, Bus 1, Stop B, Bus 3, Stop D         6
Stop A, Bus 2, Stop B, Bus 3, Stop D         6
Stop A, Bus 2, Stop C, Bus 3, Stop D         6
```

Comment: Thanks Nicole,This is what I was looking for.I added distance property to NEXT relationships between stops.I tried this query to get total distance from each possible way.But it returns null.    `MATCH (a:Stop {name:'A'}), (c:Stop {name:'C'})
MATCH p = allShortestPaths((a)-[:STOPS_AT*]-(c))
RETURN EXTRACT(x IN NODES(p) | CASE WHEN x:Stop THEN 'Stop ' + x.name
                                    WHEN x:Bus THEN 'Bus ' + x.id
                               ELSE '' END),reduce(distance=0,r in relationships(p)|distance+r.distance)as Distance`.Can you explain how this query is working internally.

Comment: I didn't realize distance was a factor - can you edit your question to include that? Your above query is returning null because you matched on the `STOPS_AT` relationship, and not the `NEXT` relationship.

Answer (score 0):

Since you can create multiple relationships between the same nodes, I would suggest creating a relationship for each bus.  So from your example:

```
A<-----------------B<-------------------------------C
   buses[180Q,171B]      buses[80A,43B,121S]
```

You might do something like:

```
<somehow MATCH on A and B>
CREATE B-[:connects_to {bus: '180Q'}]->A
CREATE B-[:connects_to {bus: '171B'}]->A
```

and so on...

That way you can do

```
MATCH path=(start {id: '123'})-[:connects_to {bus: '180Q'}*1..10]-(end: {id: '321'})
UNWIND relationships(path) AS hop
WITH path, hop
WITH path, collect(DISTINCT hop.bus) AS busses
WHERE length(busses) <= 2
RETURN path
```

Honestly I've never used both a relationship property match at the same time as a variable length specification, but I imagine it would work

Comment: I understood I can create multiple relationship between nodes. but @Brian problem is even when I got the shortest path between nodes by cypher query , I still have to programmatically check the path return by cypher query to represent the bus interchange at stations. The query does not provide me where to  interchange , it just gives me shortest path from A to B with buses details to reach at destination. I hope I am able to tell you my question.

Comment: Ah, I think maybe I understand.  Do you want to find the shortest route including transfers (getting off the bus at one stop and getting an another route)?

Comment: Yes @Brian that`s what I am looking for.Is there any way

Comment: So I've just updated the answer with a query which I haven't at all tried and which I'm not sure will work, but I suspect might be able to if you played with it some.  Also, depending on what sort of questions you want to answer, you might want to think about writing / finding unmanaged extension

Comment: Thanks @Brian I will work on the query , It looks there is something available in Neo4j for the query I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I tried quite  of cypher queries but can not get what I am looking for, the bus interchange info. Until now my query is.

```
MATCH (from:Stop { name:"A" }), (to:Stop { name: "S"}) , path = (from)-[:CONNECTED*]->(to)
unwind relationships(path) as hop
RETURN extract(n IN nodes(path)| n.name) AS Shortest_Route,collect(hop.Buses) as Buses,length(path) as Stop_Count,
reduce(distance = 0, r in relationships(path) | distance+r.distance) AS Shortest_Distance
ORDER BY Shortest_Distance ASC
LIMIT 1 .
```

I am finding it hard to get bus interchange information.I think I have to do it programatically.It does not look very complex , but I was thinking If I can get it from cypher query itself.