# How to get output from 2 different relation in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher, spring-data-neo4j

My model is  transoport system:

nodes: BusStop, Bus, TransportOperator

Relationship : BusStop-[:Stops_At]->Bus

Relationship : Bus-[Operated_By]->TransportOperator

If i use the below query i get an out put as :

QUERY:

```
MATCH (a:BusStop{name:'Bonhoefferstrasse'}),(d:BusStop {name:'HeidelBerg Hauptbanhof'})
MATCH p = allShortestPaths((a)-[:STOPS_AT*]-(d))

RETURN EXTRACT(x IN NODES(p) | CASE WHEN x:Bus THEN 'Bus' + x.id   WHEN x:BusStop THEN 'BusStop'+ x.name
ELSE '' END) AS RouteDetails
```

OUTPUT:

```
BusStopBonhoefferstrasse, Bus34, BusStopHeidelBerg Hauptbanhof
```

But from the above relationship if i want the operator to be displayed in the output how do i query ... ? does neo4j provide a feature to do this ?

For example :(This query is wrong just to give and idea what output i'm trying to get)

```
MATCH (a:BusStop{name:'Bonhoefferstrasse'}),(d:BusStop {name:'HeidelBerg Hauptbanhof'}),(e:Bus{id:''}),(f:TransportOperator{name:'Rhein-Neckar-Verkehr'})
MATCH p = allShortestPaths((a)-[:STOPS_AT*]-(d)),((e)-[:OPERATED_BY]->(f))**

RETURN EXTRACT(x IN NODES(p) | CASE WHEN x:Bus THEN 'Bus' + x.id   WHEN x:BusStop THEN 'BusStop'+ x.name WHEN x:TransportOperator THEN 'TransportOperator' ELSE '' END) AS RouteDetails
```

can i club 2 relationship (Used in above match query)?

Expected output:BusStopBonhoefferstrasse, Bus34,**RNV**, BusStopHeidelBerg Hauptbanhof

Comment: you can also use: `EXTRACT(x IN NODES(p) | CASE WHEN x:Bus THEN 'Bus' + x.id  +' Operator: ' head(extract(p in (x)-[:Operated_By]->()| last(nodes(p))).name WHEN x:BusStop THEN 'BusStop'+ x.name
ELSE '' END) AS RouteDetails` but I like Nicole's suggestion with UNWIND

Comment: Thanks for the help christophe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An expansion on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27664760/neo4j-bus-route-application-modeling/27750490):

Example data:

```
CREATE (a:Stop {name:'A'}),
       (b:Stop {name:'B'}),
       (c:Stop {name:'C'}),
       (d:Stop {name:'D'}),

       (a)-[:NEXT {distance:1}]->(b),
       (b)-[:NEXT {distance:2}]->(c),
       (c)-[:NEXT {distance:3}]->(d),

       (b1:Bus {id:1}),
       (b2:Bus {id:2}),
       (b3:Bus {id:3}),

       (o1:Operator {id:1}),
       (o2:Operator {id:2}),

       (b1)-[:OPERATED_BY]->(o1),
       (b2)-[:OPERATED_BY]->(o1),
       (b3)-[:OPERATED_BY]->(o2),

       (b1)-[:STOPS_AT]->(a),
       (b1)-[:STOPS_AT]->(b),
       (b2)-[:STOPS_AT]->(a),
       (b2)-[:STOPS_AT]->(b),
       (b2)-[:STOPS_AT]->(c),
       (b3)-[:STOPS_AT]->(b),
       (b3)-[:STOPS_AT]->(c),
       (b3)-[:STOPS_AT]->(d);
```

Solution:

```
MATCH (a:Stop {name:'A'}), (d:Stop {name:'D'})
MATCH p = allShortestPaths((a)-[:STOPS_AT*]-(d))
WITH p, FILTER(x IN NODES(p) WHERE x:Bus) AS buses
UNWIND buses AS bus
MATCH (bus)-[:OPERATED_BY]->(o:Operator)
RETURN EXTRACT(x IN NODES(p) | CASE WHEN x:Stop THEN 'Stop ' + x.name
                                    WHEN x:Bus THEN 'Bus ' + x.id
                               ELSE '' END) AS itinerary,
       COLLECT('Bus ' + bus.id + ':' + 'Operator ' + o.id) AS operators
```

Result:

```
itinerary                               operators
[Stop A, Bus 2, Stop B, Bus 3, Stop D]  [Bus 2:Operator 1, Bus 3:Operator 2]
[Stop A, Bus 1, Stop B, Bus 3, Stop D]  [Bus 1:Operator 1, Bus 3:Operator 2]
[Stop A, Bus 2, Stop C, Bus 3, Stop D]  [Bus 2:Operator 1, Bus 3:Operator 2]
```

Console: http://console.neo4j.org/r/p2xgiy