# Neo4j Get Bus Direction Route Application

Tags: neo4j, routes, direction

In a graph with trains and stops, how should i include the Train directions
I've followed this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27664760/neo4j-bus-route-application-modeling) instructions to create my model.

This is my example with two trains:

```
Create  
    (A:Stop {nameFr:'A'}),
    (B:Stop {nameFr:'B'}),
    (C:Stop {nameFr:'C'}),
    (D:Stop {nameFr:'D'}),
    (E:Stop {nameFr:'E'}),
    (F:Stop {nameFr:'F'}),
    (G:Stop {nameFr:'G'}),
    (H:Stop {nameFr:'H'}),
    (I:Stop {nameFr:'I'}),

    (A)-[:NEXT]->(B),
    (B)-[:NEXT]->(C),
    (C)-[:NEXT]->(D),
    (D)-[:NEXT]->(E),
    (E)-[:NEXT]->(F),
    (F)-[:NEXT]->(E),
    (E)-[:NEXT]->(D),
    (D)-[:NEXT]->(C),
    (C)-[:NEXT]->(B),
    (B)-[:NEXT]->(A),
    (C)-[:NEXT]->(G),
    (G)-[:NEXT]->(H),
    (H)-[:NEXT]->(I),
    (I)-[:NEXT]->(H),
    (H)-[:NEXT]->(G),
    (G)-[:NEXT]->(C),

    (R1:Train {id:'R1', directionA:'I', directionR:'A'}),
    (R1)-[:STOP_AT {order:'1'}]->(A),
    (R1)-[:STOP_AT {order:'2'}]->(B),
    (R1)-[:STOP_AT {order:'3'}]->(C),
    (R1)-[:STOP_AT {order:'4'}]->(G),
    (R1)-[:STOP_AT {order:'5'}]->(H),
    (R1)-[:STOP_AT {order:'6'}]->(I),

    (R2:Train {id:'R2', directionA:'F', directionR:'B'}),
    (R2)-[:STOP_AT {order:'2'}]->(B),
    (R2)-[:STOP_AT {order:'3'}]->(C),
    (R2)-[:STOP_AT {order:'4'}]->(D),
    (R2)-[:STOP_AT {order:'5'}]->(E),
    (R2)-[:STOP_AT {order:'6'}]->(F);
```

My Cypher Query to get routes:

```
MATCH (A:Stop {nameFr:'A'}), (F:Stop {nameFr:'F'})
MATCH p = allShortestPaths((A)-[:STOP_AT*]-(F))
RETURN EXTRACT(x IN NODES(p) | CASE WHEN x:Stop THEN 'Stop ' + x.nameFr
                                    WHEN x:Train THEN 'Train ' + x.id
                                    ELSE '' END) AS itinerary
```

My question is : How can i get the direction of the train ?

Edit: 
This is my example [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6n-YE3D5SZxM1N6XzFHYlVkRm8/view?usp=sharing) : 
Going from the stop "A" to the Stop "F" I want this result:
[Stop A, Train R1, Direction I, Stop B, Train R2, Direction F, Stop F]

Comment: Can you elaborate on what your direction properties mean? What is `directionA` and `directionR`?

Comment: "directionA" is the first way ex: R1 directionA is from A to I and "directionR" is the way bach ex: R1 directionB is from I to A

Comment: Can you give an example of what you want the output to be?

Comment: I've edited my post with my example, thank you for your help

Comment: So you always want the `directionA` property? When would you want the `directionR` property?

Comment: directionR property will be needed if want the way back:
Example: Going from the stop "F" to the Stop "A", result: [Stop F, Train R2, Direction B, Stop B, Train R1, Direction A, Stop A]