# With cypher, how can i get the less Transfer Path in my DB?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

i created a Bus Route database with neo4j, you can download it here https://www.dropbox.com/s/zamkyh2aaw3voe6/data.rar?dl=0

i want to get  the less Transfer Path, and i am doing like :

```
MATCH path=allShortestPaths((start:潍坊_STATION {name:'寒亭一村'})-[rels*..50]->(end:潍坊_STATION {name:'火车站'}))
         RETURN NODES(path) AS stations,relationships(path) AS path,
         length(FILTER(index IN RANGE(1, length(rels)-1) WHERE (rels[index]).bus <> (rels[index - 1]).bus)) AS transfer_count
         ORDER BY transfer_count
         LIMIT 10
```

But the result is not correct , who can help me ?

Comment: What is your result and what exactly do you expect to get from your query?

Comment: i want to get 10 less transfer  routes between two stations and make the result order by transfer times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this give you what you want:

```
MATCH path=allShortestPaths((start:潍坊_STATION {name:'寒亭一村'})-[rels*..50]->(end:潍坊_STATION {name:'火车站'}))
     RETURN NODES(path) AS stations,relationships(path) AS route,
     length(path) AS transfer_count
     ORDER BY transfer_count ASC
     LIMIT 10
```

This should return 10 paths connecting the two stations ordered by the length of the path. Although, the ordering here isn't needed. Since we are using the `allShortestPaths` function, all paths found will be the same length (in the case of the data you shared, 22).

You mention transfer time in your question, but I don't see the time as a property in your data. If you have the time stored you could use the `reduce` function to sum the travel time and order by that.

**Edit**

Use the `extract` function to collect the bus names from the relationships in the path:

```
MATCH 
    path=allShortestPaths((start:潍坊_STATION {name:'寒亭一村'})-[rels*..50]->(end:潍坊_STATION {name:'火车站'}))
RETURN 
    NODES(path) AS stations, relationships(path) AS route,
    length(path) AS transfer_count, extract(x in rels | x.bus) AS buses
    ORDER BY transfer_count ASC
    LIMIT 10
```

Comment: No,sir, any of the relationships has a property "bus", it is the bus name,i want to get the distinct bus name in the path

Comment: Edited answer to also return bus names in the path

Comment: I think i need to change the data model like :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27664760/neo4j-bus-route-application-modeling,  then i can get the less transfer route in a easy way