# In my Noe4j DB,With this data model , how can i get the shortest path?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, shortest-path

I am doing a Bus Route project with Neo4j database now,  and i find a solution here(Nicole White's answer):[Neo4j Bus Route Application Modeling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27664760/neo4j-bus-route-application-modeling)
.I think it is a good idea , with that data model i can get the less transfer route in a very easy way.

But, i want to add the 'walk route' between two bus station if they are very close to each other,so that user can go a short way to transfer. then how can i get the less transfer route ?

The following Solutions are what i have tried so far:

Solution 1:

i create a 'WALK_NEXT' relationship between two station that are very close to each other :
[image]
and when i use 'allShortestPaths' function , i have to use label: STOP_AT, so i can not get the path that contain  'WALK_NEXT'  relation ship

```
match path=allShortestPaths((start:STATION {name:'S1'})-[rels:STOP_AT*]-(end:STATION {name:'S5'}))    
return path
```

Solution2:

I create a 'WALK' node  between two station that are very close to each other , and link to two station with 'STOP_AT' relationship:
[image]

so that i can get the path contain 'WALK' nodes, but i think it is not a good way ,
 for 'allShortestPaths' function, i can not get the paths but only the paths that contain this  'WALK' node ,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the data model you describe for "Solution 1", you can define a variable length pattern using multiple relationship types: `(:Station)-[:STOP_AT|WALK_NEXT*]->(:Station)`. This pattern will match on paths of any length where the relationship type is `:STOP_AT` or `:WALK_NEXT` between `Station` nodes.

So your query becomes:

```
MATCH 
    path=allShortestPaths((start:Station {name:'S1'})-[rels:STOP_AT|WALK_NEXT*]->(end:Station {name:'S5'}))    
RETURN path
```

Comment: wow, thanks a lot for your answer, i did not know i can put muti label in the query . thanks