# How should I model multiple routes between nodes in Neo4j?

Tags: neo4j

How should I model multiple routes between nodes in Neo4j in order to search for the best routes between station A and C?

Should I just put the relationship between station A and B as one edge and extract bus route A from property value after searching for the shortest path?
[image]

Or, I should just separate them into 2 edges? Will it make computation a lot more complex if there are a lot more nodes and edges?
[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27750490/4989460

Comment: Thanks. I guess that solution doesn't handle the case with different roads and routes between 2 stops.  

For the case  
route 1: a->b->c->d->e  
route 2: b->d  
  
  
I guess Neo4j will suggest to change to route 2 at b and change back to route 1 at d if I go from a to e.

Comment: Also, if I add all the trips as relationship (to determine which route to wait for), there will be thousands of relationships between stations.

Answer (score -2):

I'd choose 3rd option. Combine both of yours approaches.

One relationship for "Is there a route?" and one relationship for each route type.

Cypher example

```
CREATE (a)-[r:BusRoute]->(b)
CREATE (a)-[r:BusRouteA]->(b)
CREATE (a)-[r:BusRouteB]->(b)
```

Comment: It seems to be the type of relationship can be only one? http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/terminology.html#term-relationship-type

Comment: @MicTech: A relationship can only have a single type.

Comment: Or I should put it as the same type but put the routes in attributes just like

`(a)-[r:BusRoute {route:[A,B]}]->(b)`